# AspectJ not compiling

Tags: java, maven, java-8, aspectj, dropwizard

I'm trying to use the metrics-aspectj library (https://github.com/astefanutti/metrics-aspectj) to get annotated metrics working in my Dropwizard app, but I am seeing the following exception on startup:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:aspectj-maven-plugin:1.8:compile (default) on project app: AJC compiler errors:
[ERROR] error Missing message: configure.incompatibleComplianceForSource in: org.aspectj.ajdt.ajc.messages
[ERROR] error no sources specified
[ERROR] abort AspectJ Compiler 1.8.7
```

This is what's in my pom file:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.astefanutti.metrics.aspectj</groupId>
  <artifactId>metrics-aspectj</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
  <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
  <version>1.8.10</version>
</dependency>

  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.8</source>
      <target>1.8</target>
      <aspectLibraries>
        <aspectLibrary>
          <groupId>io.astefanutti.metrics.aspectj</groupId>
          <artifactId>metrics-aspectj</artifactId>
        </aspectLibrary>
      </aspectLibraries>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>compile</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

**App Details**

- Java 8
- Dropwizard
- Multi Module Setup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [ERROR] error Missing message: configure.incompatibleComplianceForSource in: org.aspectj.ajdt.ajc.messages

Will be fixed by adding

```
<complianceLevel>1.8</complianceLevel>
```

in addition to the `<source/>` & `<target/>`

`<complianceLevel/>` defaults to `1.5` and `<source/>` `1.8`  is not backwards compatible to `1.5`.